# Sessionid is duplicated between some jboss server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

We use 2 jboss server (version 4.2.GA) and have a citrix for load balancing. 
Webserver set session-timeout: 3h

Recently, I received a serious report that:

User A login website, After a period time, User A refresh page and see profile of User B

How can it be?

Comment: Are you sure it's sessionid related? (post a log snippet?)  Bad code can do this too, such as storing data that should be session scoped (or not cached at all) in application scope.

Comment: It does not happen frequently. But I'm sure user's profile is not cached in application, it's only store in session scope

Comment: Problem can be happen if 2 jboss server generate the same sessionid (rarely). Then user A's session timeout, user A connect to the second server (through Citrix)  and then view profile of user B?